# How to read barcode information from an UIImage in Iphone??

Tags: iphone, barcode

How to read barcode information from an UIImage in Iphone? I need to match the info read from above asked way to read barcode info through iphone camera?

Comment: there are sooo many tutorials out there regarding this... and remember that **We're not a Code Generator Forum**, show us what you have accomplished so far so we can help you get back on the track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a bar code library - I find Zebra Crossing to be excellent: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: It'll take him forever to port from Java to Objective-C.

Comment: No, there's a complete iPhone project in there under /iPhone. I grabbed it this morning and couldn't believe it took all of 10 minutes to be scanning from an actual iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at zBar too.